# ASM 4bit by 4bit multiplication by software

Tags: assembly, avr, multiplication

I need to replace a ASM operation because there is no such in my architecture (avrtiny).

mul X,Y
Where X and Y is a 4bit number

I wonder what would be the fastest operation to replace mul? What I find in google was 8bit * 8bit what is not really optimal.

Comment: Fastest is probably a 256-byte lookup table. Concatenate the two operands into a single 8-bit number to index the table.

Comment: @prl That's good enough for an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @Alexey, maybe, but I don’t know anything about AVR architecture, array indexing, or memory timing, so hopefully someone who does can comment.

Comment: @prl You don't have to always provide the code.

Comment: @prl: AVR can index static arrays with an 8-bit integer just fine.  It often has some SRAM where you could pre-calculate a table for fast lookups.  Spending 256 bytes of it on a LUT might be extravagant, and I think it only has shifts of 1 bit per instruction, but if multiply throughput is paramount then this might be viable.  (AVR's ISA reference lists timings.  LSL is an alias for `add same,same`, and takes 1 cycle.   https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_LSL.html )

Comment: @Alexey, my concern isn't about not being able to provide code, but rather that it is just a guess and may not be a good answer.

Comment: From [ebalcsk's comment to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802303/asm-4bit-by-4bit-multiplication-by-software/54803066#comment96383738_54803066): *X will be always 14 Y is between [0 .. 10]*

Answer (score 2):

You can use the classical shift and add multiplication algorithm (assuming your numbers are unsigned).

It is based on the fact that a 4-bits number b<sub>3</sub>,b<sub>2</sub>,b<sub>1</sub>,b<sub>0</sub> represents number
B= 2<sup>3</sup> × b<sub>3</sub> + 2<sup>2</sup> × b<sub>2</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup> × b<sub>1</sub> + b0

And A × B = 2<sup>3</sup> × A × b<sub>3</sub> + 2<sup>2</sup> × A × b<sub>2</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup> × A × b<sub>1</sub> + A × b0

Multiplication by a bit b<sub>i</sub> will be 0 if b<sub>i</sub>≠1 and multiplication by a power of 2 is just a shift.

```
shift-and-add-multiplication
// multiply A X B -> C
C=0
for i in 0..3
  if B & 0x01
     C = C + A
  end if
  A <<=1
  B >>=1
end for
```

I do not knwon avr asm, but the code should be easy to translate.

If your numbers are signed, the simpler is to compute the product of their absolute value and to change the sign of result is sign(A)⊕sign(B)==1

There are more sophisticated algorithms, that can directly deal with signed integers and can reduce the number of steps, such as modified Booth algorithm, but implementation is more complex and I am not sure the gain will be significant.

Edit: according to comments, first operand is always 14=16-2=2<sup>4</sup>-2<sup>1</sup>.

In that case, the fastest is to compute

```
C = (B << 4) - (B << 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lookup table is surely the fastest way but probably you've got little flash to waste, I would rather use a simple sum.

Something like this (don't know you isa, I'm assuming 16bit pc).

```
mov  factor2, temp2
rla  temp2
mov  #32, temp
sub  temp2, temp
add  temp, PC
add  factor2, factor1
---copy 15 times last row---
```

Comment: Thank you 

I not really needed to program in ASM before. I think lookup table will be faster in this case. I didn’t know before this will be important:
X will be always 14
Y is between [0 .. 10]

Comment: If X is constant then a small lookup table is the right choice.

Comment: @ebalcsk  You could also implement this with shifts and subtractions.  Recall that 14 = 2 · (8 - 1), so you can compute `((Y << 3) - Y) << 1` to get the desired result.  Might not be shorter than a look-up table though.